# Salesforce handling event onTabClosed not working in lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience

I want to show a popup message on closing a lightning component to prevent data loss and as a user warning in service console app. 
For this I have implemented the below:

cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <force:workspaceAPIAccess aura:id="workspace" />    
    <aura:handler event="force:tabClosed" action="{! c.onTabClosed }"/> 

</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
onTabClosed : function(component, event, helper) {
        // you can get use: event.getParams() to get Event parameters
        // eg. var tabid = event.getParam('tabId');

        confirm("Do you really want to close this tab?");
    }
```

But though it shows the warning popup but closes the window regardless of clicking ok/Cancel on the popup.

to stop this I have already tried as desperate measure:

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.cancelBubble = true;
Event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Can you please help me with this ? How to stop the component from closing ??

Thanks in advance.